# RegionPlot of DiscretizeRegion of ImplicitRegion

Tags: plotting, regions, discretization

Writing:

```
A = ImplicitRegion[Max[Abs[x - 1 + 2 y], Abs[y - 1 - 2 x]] == 1, {x, y}]; 
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[A]]
```

I get:

[image]

while writing:

```
A = ImplicitRegion[Max[Abs[x - 1 + 2 y], Abs[y - 1 - 2 x]] == 1., {x, y}];
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[A]]
```

I get:

[image]

Why?

---

Writing:

```
a = ImplicitRegion[Max[Abs[x-1+2y], Abs[y-1-2x]] == 1., {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 2}}];
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[a, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 2}}]]
```

I get:

[image]

and so things are not going well yet!

(I have `11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)`)

Comment: Specify a region via `A = ImplicitRegion[
  Max[Abs[x - 1 + 2 y], Abs[y - 1 - 2 x]] == 
   1., {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 2}}]` works for me. Putting the region inside `DiscretizeRegion` also works: `DiscretizeRegion[A, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 2}}]`

Comment: Never use an upper-case letter, or even a name that *starts* with an upper-case letter, as a variable in *Mathematica*  (e.g., `A`) as it is likely to conflict with system variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get better results by decreasing the maximum mesh size.

```
a =
  ImplicitRegion[
    Max[Abs[x - 1 + 2 y], Abs[y - 1 - 2 x]] == 1., {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 2}}];
RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[a, MaxCellMeasure -> .00001]]
```

[image: plot]

But, really, in this case you will be much better off using exact numbers; i.e, to replace

```
Max[Abs[x - 1 + 2 y], Abs[y - 1 - 2 x]] == 1.
```

with

```
Max[Abs[x - 1 + 2 y], Abs[y - 1 - 2 x]] == 1
```

#### Update

Here is some code that will get you started on your actual problem as you described it in a comment below.

```
With[{s = 2},
  Manipulate[
    Graphics[
      {EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], FaceForm[None], 
       Translate[Rotate[sqFrame, inclination °], position]},
      Frame -> True,
      PlotRange -> 5 s,
      ImageSize -> 400],
    {{position, {0, 0}}, 4.5 s {-1, -1}, 4.5 s {1, 1}, .25, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{inclination, 0}, -90, 90, 5, AppearanceElements -> All},
    Initialization :> (
      sqFrame =
        Polygon[
          TranslationTransform[-s {1, 1}/2][{{0, 0}, {s, 0}, {s, s}, {0, s}}]])]]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: @TeM. That is a very different and much easier question to answer. Simply define a square in terms of its center and its boundary polygon, then use the built-in geometric transforms `Rotate` and `Translate` to control the motion of the square in your graphics viewport. The results will be much faster than fooling around with regions.